# Not getting images as per modal popup

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-modal

Here, I am showing different image with different content. I have used modal popup to show read more content. Images are showing outside the modal popup are right but when I select read more modal popup, I am getting same image as the first one in all modal popup. 
My code is like below:

```
 <div class="row">
                                <?php 
                                        if( have_rows('blog_sub_content') ): 
                                        $i=0;
                                        while( have_rows('blog_sub_content') ): the_row(); 

                                        $blg_image          = get_sub_field('blg_image');
                                        $blg_title          = get_sub_field('blg_title');
                                        $blg_posted_name    = get_sub_field('blg_posted_name');
                                        $blg_content        = get_sub_field('blg_content');


                                        ?>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="single-blog">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $blg_image['url'] ; ?>" alt="" />
                                            <h2><?php echo $blg_title; ?></h2>
                                            <ul class="post-meta">
                                                <li><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i><strong> Posted By:</strong> <?php echo $blg_posted_name; ?></li>
                                                <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><strong> Posted On:</strong> Apr 15 2014</li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <div class="blog-content">
                                                <?php echo substr(strip_tags($blg_content), 0, 144);  ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#blog-detail">Read More</a>
                                        </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="blog-detail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                        <img src="<?php echo $blg_image['url']; ?>" alt="" />
                                                        <h2><?php echo $blg_title; ?></h2>
                                                        <?php echo $blg_content; ?>
                                                    </div> 
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php

                                    if($i==2)
                                    { ?>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <?php }
                                    $i++;
                                        endwhile;  
                                        endif; 

                                        ?>

                                    </div> 
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer:

I have to use `$i` for different `id` to call it like this:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#blog-detail_<?php echo $i;?>">Read More</a>
```

And then,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="blog-detail_<?php echo $i;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
```

The full code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="single-blog">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $blg_image['url'] ; ?>" alt="" />
                                        <h2><?php echo $blg_title; ?></h2>
                                        <ul class="post-meta">
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i><strong> Posted By:</strong> <?php echo $blg_posted_name; ?></li>
                                            <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><strong> Posted On:</strong> Apr 15 2014</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="blog-content">
                                            <?php echo substr(($blg_content), 0, 147);  ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#blog-detail_<?php echo $i;?>">Read More</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="blog-detail_<?php echo $i;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $blg_image['url']; ?>" alt="" />
                                                    <h2><?php echo $blg_title; ?></h2>
                                                    <?php echo $blg_content; ?>
                                                </div> 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Great, just for those who can't see (as you should really have explained), all of your IDs for the modals had the same id, so only the first one was being shown. You would need to make them unique, and likewise the call to the modal from the source button.